# Angular animate each item in array with different timeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to convert an app that's coded using **jQuery** to one that's using **Angular** *as well*.

I've got a few arrays containing similar data in a variable called `categories`:

```
.controller('AppController', function($scope,$timeout){
  var self=this;
  self.categories=[[],[],[]];
  self.selected=0;
  setInterval(getNewItems,500);
});
```

I display the data using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div id="numbers">
  <div class="slide" ng-repeat="number in app.categories[app.selected]">{{number}}</div>
</div>
```

And let the user switch *selected category* with the following navigation:

```
<li ng-repeat="category in app.categories">
  <a href="#" ng-click="app.selected=$index">
    Array #{{$index}}: {{category.length}} items
  </a>
</li>
```

There needs to be an animation when the server sends new items to the arrays and when old items are removed. This was easy to achieve with `ngAnimate`:

```
.animation('.slide',function(){
  return{
    enter:function($e,done){
      var height=$e.height();
      $e.css({
        left:$e.parent().width(),
        height:0
      }).animate({
        left:0,
        height:height
      },done);
    },
    leave:function($e,done){
      $e.animate({
        left:-$e.parent().width(),
        height:0
      });
    },
    move:function($e,done){
      done()
    }
  }
});
```

Animations when adding/removing elements work great, as demonstrated in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/ukq7ehca/ . However, when switching between arrays, the animation is ugly compared to what I had previously achieved with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/14qtm70z/1/ . Rather than each of the elements in the array sliding simultaneously, I'd like them to leave/enter one-by-one at 50ms intervals as seen in the second fiddle. **Is this possible in Angular?** Do I perhaps have to change the structure of the page to achieve it?

Furthermore, if you're going to suggest I switch from **jQuery animations** to **CSS animations** when using **Angular**... Please also show how to animate the `height` of the added elements from `0` to `auto` with an `ease-in-out` easing curve. Unlike in the Fiddles above, the data in the actual app may be multiple lines long. Otherwise, **jQuery animation solutions only**, please :)

Comment: IMO, jQuery is far better for animations, and animation plugins. I think angular makes a half arsed attempt to cover animations, but it will never be able to cover the sheer scale of jQuery plugins available. I think law of the instrument applies to angularsjs sometimes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with two thing :

1 - ng-class on your element to animate

```
 <myElement ng-class="{myanimatedclass : myCTRL.myboolean1}"></my-element>
 <myElement ng-class="{myanimatedclass : myCTRL.myboolean2}"></my-element>
```

2 - in your controller you can set the interval for each boolean

```
function myController() { 
  vm = this;
  vm.myboolean1 = false;
  vm.myboolean2 = false;

function boolean1totru() {
   vm.myboolean1 = true;
  }

  function boolean2totru() {
   vm.myboolean2 = true;
  }

  function init() {
    setInterval(boolean1totrue,500);
    setInterval(boolean2totrue,1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your solution is trying to do, but it seems that it just starts setting the same boolean to `true` over and over after the controller has been initialized. Not sure how this helps.

Comment: no sorry it's two boolean. In fact with the ng-class function you will be abble to play the animation when the boolean will pass to true. So if you have two elements to animate you can set two boolean on it. And in your controller you will be abble to choose the duration before animating each elements